# Which API provides the website URL for a cryptocurrency?

Tags: api

I've been searching for an API that returns the website/URL for a cryptocurrency. Is there any public API which provides the website for a specific cryptocurrency?

Comment: "the website for a specific cryptocurrency" A lot of currencies like Bitcoin are decentralized and don't have ONE website. I don't understand why someone should write an API to provide links.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

CryptoCompare's API has the website URLs if you use CoinSnapshopFullById:

[CryptoCompare API](https://www.cryptocompare.com/api/#-api-data-coinsnapshotfullbyid-)